# Getting issue in formatting date column when import CSV file in SQL Server Management studio

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssms

I have a date column which as a combination of date (2020/01/01) data and character (ABCDEF) in CSV file which is import in SSMS

When I'm trying format using `CAST(Transaction_date as Datetime)` I'm getting the below error

> Conversion failed when converting and/or time form Character string

I need to convert only the date in the column not character

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWTIk.png)

Comment: We don't know what exactly you are doing, we can't see your screen, we don't know your goal, and we can't read your mind. Is this an issue with the process you are using to import data into a table? Or is this a problem with information you have already imported and that now exists in a table and some query is failing? Something else? Provide **context**. And why do you cast to datetime if your source is only a (poorly formed) date?

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` will convert the dates that it can, and leave those that it can't as `NULL`. However I agree with @SMor, please provide some additional context, it would be useful to know why your CSV file has ABCDEF in a date column and what you want to do with that data instead. It is possible you could load the CSV into a staging table that just has string columns and then you can further process that table based on what got loaded.